# How do I disable the eventual fairness of the Rust parking_lot crate's Mutex?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, mutex

I have a prior assurance that a rayon par_iter's threads will only lock a Mutex once each for a batch of work, and since I have no thread starving concerns, have no need to incur the (apparently 0.5ms) overhead of parking_lot's eventual fairness guarantee. Parking_lot still offers other benefits I would like to take advantage of.
Is it possible to configure the parking_lot Mutex to disable the fairness guarantees?

Here's some simplified init and generic work:

```
let mut map: Vec<Vec<Mutex<HashSet<u64>>>> = Vec::with_capacity(WIDTH);
for i in 0..WIDTH {
  map.push(Vec::with_capacity(HEIGHT));
  for _ in 0..HEIGHT {
    map[i].push(Mutex::new(HashSet::new()));
  }
}

let mut diff: Vec<(usize, usize, u64)> = /* some code to fill this with numbers */
diff.par_iter().for_each(|(x, y, id)| {
  map[x][y].lock().insert(id);
});
```

At the scale I'm at this is a lot faster than the serial approach, but it's on the hot path and even half-millisecond time gains are important for my usecase.

Things I've tried:
I asked my old pal ChatGPT, and it told me to try

```
parking_lot::lock_api::Mutex<HashSet<u64, parking_lot::RawMutex>>
```

However this resulted in strange errors. Looking at the docs, there is apparently some use for the lock_api, but I'm not really groking the example, nor whether or not it could help me achieve my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parking_lot` doesn't have 0.5ms overhead. What `parking_lot` has is a guarantee that if a thread keeps locking and unlocking the same `Mutex`, then it will use a fair version of the unlock function on average once every 0.5ms (and every time the thread keeps the `Mutex` locked for more than 1ms). This fair unlock function incurs slightly more overhead than an unfair unlock but it will still be in the order of a few microseconds at most.

Anyway, if each thread locks and releases the `Mutex` only once for a short time, then it will never need to use the fair unlock so it will never incur the extra overhead.

Comment: You're right and I definitely misread that part. I'm pleased to hear that this shouldn't be a problem and am willing to mark this as answered.
Though I'll confess that a boyish curiosity has me burning for the actual solution to disable the feature, if only to learn how that kind of thing could be done.